# Relation between dropdown structure and proccessing it's data in forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've known three ways for creating dropdowns which I can use in forms till now:
1) using HTML "form-dedicated":select and option value=""
2) using Bootstrap framework: div class="dropdown" Button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" and div class="dropdown-menu having a class="dropdown-item"
3) using HTML UL-list: ul li a href="x" and so on

Could anyone tell me if there are any differences in treating data from this three types of dropdowns by server? Which one I should use to obtain not only good looking but also efficient form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only CSS and JS differences, But all of it are HTML, Frameworks are a ready CSS-JavaScript codes, A drop-down inside a form is connected to the form, That all.

Comment: Ok, putting frameworks aside and dig into it a little - what if I will create 2 dropdowns one using select with options tag and second with ul-li construction - as you wrote there would be no difference on server side - Java or PHP won't "see" any difference BUT what difference it will be for Javascript ?

Comment: `ul-li` is used for unordered lists, Bootstrap uses it inside `<option>` Because the drop-down style to be edited, you need to put `ul-li` for it, You will face this problem when you try to edit the style of drop-down menus, Some people will tell you to put the options inside `ul-li` to style it using JS or CSS, And this has nothing to do with the PHP, You the one telling PHP what to do with anything.